# Creating scrollview for custom dialog box in Swift

Tags: autolayout, swift4, xcode10.2

I have custom dialog box which has following contents
  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYgm9.png)

I wanted to know what constraints i have to give for view which is under scrollView, I also 
  want View dynamically grow so that whenever needed scrollView can appear.
  If you could help me I'll appreciate.